# jQuery and long int ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I've faced with a next problem:

In our database we have objects with ids, like 4040956363970588323.
I'm writing some client-wizard on [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) for interacting with such objects. Client receives base data about objects trough an [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request, like:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/api/pages/",
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {"id": site_id},
        success: function(data){
            if (data.success){
                for (var pidx in data.pages){
                    console.log(data.pages[pidx].id);
                    var li = $('<li class="ui-widget-content"></li>');
                    var idf = $('<input type="hidden" id="pid" value="{0}"/>'.format(data.pages[pidx].id))
                    var urlf = $('<input type="hidden" id="purl" value="{0}"/>'.format(data.pages[pidx].url))
                    li.text(data.pages[pidx].title);
                    li.append(idf);
                    li.append(urlf);
                    $("#selectable_pages_assign").append(li);
                }
                pages_was = $("#selectable_pages_assign>li");
            }
            else
                 updateTips(data.message);
        },
        error: function(){
             updateTips("Internal erro!");
        }
})
```

So, as you see I send data like [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) object (a bit of server code):

```
return HttpResponse(dumps({
                        "success": True,
                        "pages": [{"id": page.id, "title": page.title, "url": page.image} for page in Page.objects.filter(site = site)]
            }))
```

According to [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug), server send right ids in data, but `console.log(..)` instead of correct id (4040956363970588323), outputs `id         4040956363970588000`.

Why does this happen?

Without right ids, any chance, that my wizard will work correctly :)

Comment: FWIW, your error message says `updateTips("Internal erro!");` (typo on the word "error"). Which is kind of amusing :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess is something is going wrong in the conversion to JSON. When you write the value, you'll probably need to put quotes around it, to make sure it's treated as a string.

Comment: And how do you do that? I'm grabbing a value from HTML5 data and trying to treat it as a string but it's still being rounded incorrectly: `'' + $(this).data('id') + ''`. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

That looks like some kind of overflow problem to me.

According to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-to) here on SO, JavaScript can only handle INTs of size 2^64, which means the max INT is somewhere around

```
184467440737100000
```

which is much less than

```
4040956363970588323
```

EDIT: Sorry, the largest exact integer is 2^53, but the case is the same.

Comment: JavaScript numbers are IEEE 754 double-precision floating point values, with the sole qualification that the ECMAScript standard on which JavaScript is based provides only a single `NaN` value rather than perhaps more.  Thus, you lose integer precision when when you exceed the precision of the representation, which exactly preserves all integers with magnitude less than 2**53, and only preserves some integers outside that range (ones with nice binary representations, more or less, thinning out as magnitude increases until complete overflow occurs to the infinity values).